# How to deactivate virtualenv in Makefile?

Tags: python, shell, makefile

I am currently trying to create a makefile that detects, if a Python venv is active and if so, to deactivate it.
So far my attempts have not been successful.
Therefore my question, is it even possible to deactivate the current shells venv with make and if so, how?

Update: I want to make sure, that devs do not accidentally install poetry directly in their projects venv.

My ideas so far:

```
install: # Install poetry and dependencies
ifneq (,$(findstring .venv,$(VIRTUAL_ENV)))
    @echo $(VIRTUAL_ENV)
    @echo "venv active"
#   @.$(VIRTUAL_ENV)/bin/activate deactivate
    @./scripts/deactivate_venv.sh deactivate_venv
#   @exit "Please deactivate venv before running install command"
else
    @echo "No venv activated"
    @pip install poetry==1.4.0
    @poetry install
endif
```

The bash script linked to make

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

deactivate_venv(){
  echo $VIRTUAL_ENV
  source $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate deactivate
}

"$@"
```

Comment: `virtualenv` sets the environment variable `VIRTUAL_ENV` to the path of the environment when activated. Not sure what you mean by "deactivate".

Comment: I updated my question so my intentions are hopefully clear. By deactivating venv, I mean regular venv deactivation. :confused:

Comment: You want to deactivate the .venv for the parent shell, i.e. the shell, where make was called from? Or while executing some commands in the makefile, i.e. for child processes of make? Also I do not get the why.

Comment: Let me rephrase my intention then. We are using poetry to manage our project, including creation of venvs. To avoid accidental installation of poetry in the projects venv itself (as described in the documentation), I want to ensure that the venv is first deactivated and then run pip install poetry on the global Python installation. 
I am open to different approaches.

Comment: Using `make` to provision a development machine sounds a bit awkward. Installation of `poetry` should take place long before anyone who might already be using a `poetry`-managed project has activated a virtual environment, and isn't something that should need to be done later.

Comment: That is true, but to ensure that both local and CI poetry versions match, I need some logic to validate it. Or is this not necessary? 
Additionally, not all devs are on the same level and to ease the setup, I want to support them in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to deactivate virtualenv in Makefile?
> is it even possible to deactivate the current shells venv with make

I spent some time on this and my conclusion is: *it is not possible to deactivate a virtual environment created in the shell calling the make*. Here is why:

According to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Execution.html),

> When it is time to execute recipes to update a target, they are executed by invoking a new sub-shell for each line of the recipe
> **Please note:** this implies that setting shell variables and invoking shell commands such as cd that set a context local to each process will not affect the following lines in the recipe.

So this mean that each line you execute in your Makefile is sent to a new shell; since `deactivate` is a shell function stored in the caller shell memory, it's not transferred to the shells make will start, making the lines you execute unaware that it exists.

I understand this will not help your (OP) situation, but for future readers, a pattern that could possibly be available to you is something like this:

```
pyvenvtest:
    @doThis; source myvenv/Scripts/activate; doThatInTheVenv;deactivate; doSomethingElseWhitoutTheVenv
```

So the idea is to activate the venv, do your thing within the context, and deactivate it *on the same line*. So if you want to actually deactivate it, you'll have to activate it yourself on the same line. But you'll never have access to the outside venv.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit blunt, but it will do this job:

> I want to make sure, that devs do not accidentally install poetry directly in their projects venv.

Since the name of the active virtual environment, if any, is available from the `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable, you can form a prerequisite name that concatenates an existing target name and `$(VIRTUAL_ENV)`.  Then, if that variable is defined and non-null, and an attempt is made to build a target that depends on said prerequisite, it will fail with a "no rule to make target" error.  Not exactly graceful, but simple and effective.

Example:

```
all: install-poetry$(VIRTUAL_ENV)

install-poetry:
        pip install poetry==1.4.0
        poetry install
```

It is possible to work around the blockage by specifying the `install-poetry` target to `make` explicitly, but that's a feature, not a bug.

This is not the sort of thing that you would want to ship to customers, but as an internal control to help your devs avoid a known mistake, its simplicity is attractive.  To me, anyway.

**Addendum**:

As @MadScientist pointed out in comments, as long as you're willing to assume GNU's implementation of `make` (which you seem already to be doing), you can get a clearer and friendlier diagnostic in the venv cases by adding a pattern rule to handle them, something like this:

```
install-poetry%:
        @echo virtual environment set - no poetry for you
        @exit 1
```

Comment: You could also add a pattern rule to give a nicer error: `install-poetry%: ; @echo virtual env set; exit 1` or something like that.

Comment: Good point, @MadScientist.  I try to avoid leaning on GNU-isms unnecessarily, but it does appear that the OP is already assuming GNU `make`, so something along those lines might be nice.  Added.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanations. About the original title of my question, do I assume correctly, that it is than not possible to deactivate the venv from within make? So parent / subshell problem, right?